# Non-standard proofs of standard theorems

Tags: arithmetic, model-theory

In Richard Kaye's book *Models of Peano arithmetic*, one can read (page 13):

> We have proved that any nonstandard $M \models \mathrm{Th}(\mathbb{N})$ has a nonstandard $a \in M \models \theta(a)$ iff there are infinitely many $k \in \mathbb{N}$ satisfying $\mathbb{N} \models \theta(\underline{k})$. This observation is the basis of many elegant "non-standard" proofs of theorems about $\mathbb{N}$.

where $\theta(x)$ is a formula over the language $\mathcal{L}_A= \{0,1,+,\times ,<\}$ with only one free-variable $x$.

Do you know such elegant proofs?

Comment: Kaye's book also presents several examples. Recently, nonstandard techniques along these lines have been used by Tao and his collaborators in additive combinatorics.

Comment: (There was an inaccuracy in the previous version of this comment.) The unprovability in $\mathsf{PA}$ of the Paris-Harrington theorem is an example. In general, most independence results that can be established by the method of indicators. Other examples of such independent statements are that Hercules wins all Hercules-Hydra games, or the termination of Goodstein sequences.

Comment: Most introductory texts in non-standard analysis will also have examples, though some may only give examples in the context of $\mathbb R$ or similar structures, rather than $\mathbb N$.

Comment: @AndresCaicedo The Wikipedia article for Paris Harrington says that it is itself a statement about unprovability of another theorem, the "strengthened Ramnsey theorem." Do you really mean that the above is used to show that "(SRT is true but unprovable) is unprovable." Or is the Wikipedia page wrong?

Comment: (@ThomasAndrews I meant the unprovability of the strengthened Ramsey theorem.)

Answer (score 4):

Here is an example although it is more a theorem about $\mathbb{Z}$ than about $\mathbb{N}$. However, it uses the overspill principle for nonstandard models of $\mathbb{Z}$ which is essentially the same as for $\mathbb{N}$. So, I hope it counts.

I show that for any irreducible polynomial $f \in \mathbb{Q}[X]$ with integer coefficients, there are infinitely many primes $p$ such that $f$ splits completely in $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$. Let $n$ be the degree of $f$ and let $K$ be the splitting field for $f$ over $\mathbb{Q}$. Note that we can write $K=\mathbb{Q}(a_1,...,a_n)$ where $f=(X-a_1)...(X-a_n)$. So, the $a_i$ are all the roots and they must be distinct. (Remember that all irreducible polynomials from $\mathbb{Q}$ are separable.) Choose a primitive Element $b \in K$ so that we can write $K=\mathbb{Q}(b)$. Let $g$ be the minimal polynomial for $b$. We can assume that $g$ has integer coefficients. Now, let $M$ be a nonstandard model for $\mathbb{Z}$ in the language of rings. There is a well-known theorem stating that $g$ has a root modulo $p$ for infinitely many primes $p \in \mathbb{Z}$. Since the statement "$g$ has a root modulo $p$ and $p$ is prime" can be expressed by a first-order formula in the language of rings, it follows by overspill that $g$ has a root modulo a nonstandard prime $p \in M$. So, $g$ has a root in the field $M/pM$. Since $M/pM$ has characteristic $0$, it contains an isomorphic copy of $\mathbb{Q}(b)$. It follows that $f$ splits completely in $M/pM$ and has $n$ distinct roots there. Let $\theta(p)$ be a first order formula stating that $f$ has $n$ distinct roots modulo $p$ and that $p$ is a prime. Then $M \vDash \theta(p)$. Since $p$ is non-standard, underspill gives us the desired result.

There is an easy generalization: You can prove the statement also for finitely many irreducible polynomials $f_1,...,f_n$ from $\mathbb{Q}[X]$ with integer coefficients. The proof is essentially the same as above. Just use the splitting field for the product $\prod_i f_i$.